# Is there a way to test Laravel's email configuration to check if it connects with the server?

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a CMS-like installer for my laravel project. I have updated the laravel.env file.
Now, I want to test the email configuration, I end up getting this error:
[image]

This is my controller code:

```
    public function processEmailConfig(){
        // // Create tables
        // Artisan::call('migrate:fresh', ['--force' => true]);
        // // Run seeder
        // Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--force' => true]);
        $data = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
            'mail_host' => 'required',
            'mail_port' => 'required|numeric',
            'mail_username' => 'required',
            'mail_password' => 'required',
            'mail_encryption' => 'required',
            'mail_from' => 'required',
        ]);
        if($data->fails()){
            return response()->json(['errors'=>$data->errors()->all()]);
        }
        $data = $data->validated();
        $this::updateEnv('MAIL_HOST', $data['mail_host']);
        $this::updateEnv('MAIL_PORT', $data['mail_port']);
        $this::updateEnv('MAIL_USERNAME', $data['mail_username']);
        $this::updateEnv('MAIL_PASSWORD', $data['mail_password']); 
        $this::updateEnv('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', $data['mail_encryption']);
        $this::updateEnv('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', $data['mail_from']);
        try {
            Mail::to('info@chibuezevince.me')->send(new WelcomeEmail);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>['Incorrect Email Configuration']]);
        }
        return response()->json(['success'=>['Success']]);
    }
```

Please, how do I go about it?

I tried:

```
        try {
            Mail::to('info@chibuezevince.me')->send(new WelcomeEmail);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['errors'=>['Incorrect Email Configuration']]);
        }
```

But as you can see, it still gives the same error.

Comment: looks like you don't have something running on port `8000` or you don't have access to it, are you using Docker? We need more info

Comment: I am not using docker and the application is currently serving at localhost:8000

Comment: I believe the problem is related to your updateEnv. Did you check if the env vars are being updated? Also, `Mail` gonna read from `config` and at this point of the app the config vars already have being read so change the env vars wouldn't have any impact. You should change at this point the config vars used by `Mail`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that the connection to the server always restarts whenever you make any changes to the .env file. How then do I go about testing the email configuration? *Edit* ie without tampering with the env file.